# Pandas formats the file in an unusual way and removes some metrics

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am facing a problem opening a csv file with pandas.
Here is what I get.

[image: pb]

I thought to transform row data into a string and then split them at `;`. Unfortunately,
`dataset.iloc[0]` outputs

```
age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"    30;"unemployed";"married";"primary";"no";1787;...
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And `dataset.iloc[5]` outputs the following:

```
age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"balance";"housing";"loan";"contact";"day";"month";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"y"    35;"management";"single";"tertiary";"no";747;"...
Name: 5, dtype: object
```

Not all data are available in `iloc` command.
However, when I Double-click on the file to open it, I can see that it is well formatted.

[image: normal file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `sep=";"` to your `read_csv` command:

```
pd.read_csv(dfile, header=0, sep=';')
```